# Is there a faster way to search for a value in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, search, html-table

I have a html table with almost 1000 rows that needs to have a search function. I want to make this search automatic, so it starts searching for the query as the user starts to enter the string. This isn't that hard, but the nature of the search causes the page to slow down for a few seconds after the first character or two are input into my search bar.

Here is the code for the search:

```
const cols = search_drop.value;
const itemsArr = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

for (const ele of itemsArr) {
    const lower_case_search_value = this.value.toLowerCase();
const lower_case_table_value = ele.querySelector(`td[headers="${cols}"]`).innerText.toLowerCase();

    if (!lower_case_table_value.includes(lower_case_search_value)) {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        ele.style.display = 'table-row';
    }
}
```

I already tried to search for everything in the background without re-rendering the elements every time, but the slowdown remains. Any tips to speed this up?

Comment: That selector seems pretty inefficient. And why do all of your cells have a `headers` attribute?

Comment: Just drill down through `table.rows[i].cells[j]`.

Comment: You can store `td` value as a data attribute and take advantages of "CSS search" by a smart selector.

Comment: I'd use setTimeout and do this in its own thread. That way you won't sense the slowdown as the function runs

Comment: Thanks. I'll try all of these. @Bergi the headers represent one of the columns the user will search in.

Comment: @ControlAltDel `setTimeout` doesn't spawn a new thread. At best, it's useful for debouncing, but the DOM operations will always happen on the main thread.

Comment: @MARS Don't store the column names in the attributes. Just get the index of that column, and then access the respective cell in each row directly.

Comment: @Bergi Good Idea. Trying it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, that you can either store `td` text as a data attribute and take advantages of attribute search (see https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_contain.asp) or you can precalculate indices of a table (matrix) by putting them in relation to a given text, then all you need is to iterate over a collection, which is a linear time (and better in a sense that you do not interact with DOM).